# How to log an entity that has collections?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.4, doctrine-extensions, stofdoctrineextensions

I want to log all changes of an entity. I looked into [Loggable](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/loggable.md) doctrine extension as provided by the StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle.

I got it working for fields that store simple data, e.g. string and integers. But my entity also has ManyToMany relationship to another entity, e.g. `Tags`.

I am getting this error:

```
InvalidMappingException: Cannot versioned [tags] as it is collection in object - Hn\AssetDbBundle\Entity\Asset
```

Is there a way to log an entity with its relationships? I don't mind switching to another bundle.

Comment: Here is a [related issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/issues/1160).

Answer (score 7):

Currently no bundles/extensions have this functionality out of the box. One option would be to implement it yourself. This can be done by making use of [Doctrine Listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html). Particularly you need to listen to `postUpdate` and `postPersist` events - these happen when entity is updated and created and store your Tags there.

Another option is to get rid of `ManyToMany` relationship. For this create an intermediate entity `AssetTag` that would have `OneToMany` relationship to both `Asset` and `Tag`. After this is done, you can use [EntityAudit](https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit) Doctrine Extension, which supports this type of relationships.

Comment: Note that Loggable can detect the creation of the intermediate entity too.